# Show/Hide list element on live search

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to build a live search feature using js. I have a basic blog built from scratch and I want to implement the search feature. I get the posts from the database using php like so: (the database query is not that important here, I just wanted to show you how I display my posts)

```
echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 postCol">';
    echo '<li class="list">';
    echo '<h1 class="titles"><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h1>';
    echo '<p>Posted on '.date('jS M Y', strtotime($row['postDate'])).' by '.'<span class="author-name">'.$row1['username'].'</span>'.'</p>';
    echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';
    echo '<div class="imgT">';
        echo '<img class="img-responsive" src="'.$row2['imgLoc'].'"'.'/>';
    echo '</div>';         
    echo '<div class="read-more"><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More >></a></div>'; 
    echo '</li>';
echo '</div>';
```

So, I want to search the titles of each post and see if there is a match, if there is, I want to show just that specific post and hide the rest of them.
I found this js script on the internet and I tried to modify it but I just can't figure it out.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#filter").keyup(function(){

            // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
            var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;

            // Loop through the comment list
            $(".titles a").each(function(){

                // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
                if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                    $(".list").hide();

                // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
                } else {
                    $(".list").show();
                    count++;
                }
            });

            // Update the count
            var numberItems = count;
            $("#filter-count").text("Number of Comments = "+count);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I know if I do this each time I find the match it will hide them all which is not what I want but I don't know how to do it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `$('.list')` selects all elements with the class `list`, so you're hiding/showing all of them when looping. you need to get the `list` relative to the current `.titles a`: `$(this).closest('.list')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refer `.list` with respect to current `element` in `$.each`. Below are the probable changes you might wanna do.

```
// Loop through the comment list
$(".titles a").each(function() {
  var listParent=$(this).closest('li.list'); //get the closest parent with class .list
  // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
  if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
    listParent.hide(); //hide the proper parent
    // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
  } else {
    listParent.show(); //show the proper parent
    count++;
  }
});
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks for your answer. I understood now. :)

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)